# How to compare elements of two lists and find matching ones using the contains in flutter method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two lists, the first list is `filters.amenities` and the second list is `q.chargingStation!.amenities`. I need to iterate over each row in q.chargingStation!.amenities and compare whether filters.amenities contains at least one row from the q.chargingStation!.amenities list. If it contains, then fulfill the condition. I've created methods to iterate over these lists, but now how do I compare them so that the contains method works?

```
  if (getNameAmenitiesList(filters.amenities).contains(q.chargingStation!.amenities)) {
    print('Working');
  }

  List<String> getNameAmenitiesList(List<String> amenities) {
    final List<String> result = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < amenities.length; i++) {
      result.add(amenities[i]);
    }
    return result;
  }

  String getNameAmenitiesFromStationList(
      List<AmenitiesModel>? amenitiesFromList) {
    String result = '';

    for (int i = 0; i < amenitiesFromList!.length; i++) {
      result = amenitiesFromList[i].name;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: what's the point of `getNameAmenitiesList`? It doesn't do anything useful. It turns a `List<String>` into exactly the same `List<String>`

Comment: Yes I understand. But I didn’t redo anything, so I wanted to know how I can fix the error so that the method works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
if (filters.amenities.any((e) => q.chargingStation!.amenities.contains(e))) {
  print('Working');
}
```

If you need to compare the name instead do

```
if (filters.amenities.any((e) => q.chargingStation!.amenities.map((a) => a.name).contains(e))) {
  print('Working');
}
```

Comment: I need here q.chargingStation!.amenities.contains to get the value of name in order to compare strings

Comment: q.chargingStation!.amenities[index].name

Comment: @Max see my edit

Comment: Will this work if at least one field matches and the other fields do not match?